# Output not as i desire

Tags: html, angularjs

I have created an html file with angularjs as follows:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app='myApp'>
    <head>
    <title>AnguarJS</title>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller='bodyController'>
    <p>{{name}}</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

the problem is that if i provide an angular.js file as a source i am getting the output as {{name}} but if i provide the url in the script src then i am getting the desired output.
can anyone please explain to me why is this happening?

PS: the controller.js code:

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    function bodyController($scope){
        $scope.name= 'Syed Rameez Khalid';
    }
```

Comment: Could you please ask your question another way, I am not sure what the issue is?

Comment: What do you mean by `provide an angular.js file as a source`? please elaborate this..its confusing to me

Comment: Seeing uncompiled Angular expressions in the output, i.e. `{{ }}`, likely means that you have an error. Open the console and check. Make sure that you are actually providing the right path to the angular.js source file

Comment: your title gives us no information. of course a broken program would have "output not as I desire".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have angular.min.js and html file at the same location.